# (Javascript in Symfony4) - Path function not working

Tags: ajax, symfony, url, path

The {{ path }} function when used in JavaScript is not working in Symfony 4.  Just some background:

```
$ bin/console debug:router
```

Produces:

```
add_post_comment                     ANY      ANY      ANY    /comment/add/post
```

In my JavaScript file, here is what my AJAX call looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ path('/comment/add/post') }}",  // I also tried "{{ path('add_post_comment') }}"
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        "userId": userId,
        "postId": postId,
        "commentText": commentText
    },
    async: true,
    success: function (data)
    {
        alert("success!");
        console.log(data)
        $('div#ajax-results').html(data.output);

    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error - " + errorThrown + "  - textStatus is "  + textStatus);
        console.log("Error in saving comment to database: " + errorThrown);
        console.log(errorThrown);
        console.log("XMLHttpRequest is: ");
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
    }

});
```

Then when I debug everything in the JavaScript console, it produces:

```
http://------.-------.com/%7B%7B%20path('/comment/add/post')%20%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

So the path command is not actually compiling.

Here is what my composer.json looks like:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.67",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-symfony": "^2.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.0",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.8",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.2",
        "symfony/asset": "^4.1",
        "symfony/console": "^4.1",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "^4.1",
        "symfony/expression-language": "^4.1",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
        "symfony/form": "^4.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.1",
        "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.3",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/process": "^4.1",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "^4.1",
        "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.2",
        "symfony/translation": "^4.1",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.1",
        "symfony/validator": "^4.1",
        "symfony/web-link": "^4.1",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.1",
        "twig/extensions": "^1.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "^4.1",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.5",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
        "symfony/test-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^4.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use {{ .. }} in js file since it can be used only in twig file. Try providing the last word of the url like url: 'post'

Comment: Refer this https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/generate_url_javascript.html

Comment: The problem is, that your JS files are not rendered by twig. You either have to render them in twig, e.g. by using the FrameworkBundle's TemplateController passing your js file as template or embeding the JS inside your twig files or use the FOSJsRoutingBundle as suggested in the link posted by @VinothKumar

Comment: Hi guys, I think I'm close now, but it just doesn't see the actual route, can one of you have a look at my post?  It's at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53890929/symfony-4-fos-js-routing-bundle-the-route-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

Include your code inside another twig which you are sure of that it is rendered already as a twig. (like your base.html.twig or even better: only twig files that are actually going to need this piece of code)

The twig file located in SomeBundle in the folder Resources/views/Someotherfolder with name "myjavascript.html.twig" can look like this:

```
<script>
    // Your javascript code here
    var myvar = "{{ path('add_post_comment') }}";
</script>
```

This file you include inside another twig file

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% include 'SomeBundle:Someotherfolder:myjavascript.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Or when your code in the file myjavascript.html.twig is without "script" tags like:

```
// Your javascript code here
var myvar = "{{ path('add_post_comment') }}";
```

You need to put it inside other script tags

```
{% block javascripts %}
    <script>
        {% include 'SomeBundle:Someotherfolder:myjavascript.html.twig' %}
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```