# (Symfony 4) FOS Js Routing Bundle - The route ------- does not exist.

Tags: javascript, routes, symfony4

It seems like the routing yml file isn't being picked up by the Fos Js Routing bundle.  Here's what I have done so far:

Setup:

```
$./composer.phar  require friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle
$bin/console assets:install --symlink public
$bin/console fos:js-routing:dump --format=json --target=public/js /fos_js_routes.json
```

In base.html.twig:

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
```

In a separate .js module file:

```
const routes = require('../../public/js/fos_js_routes.json');
import Routing from '../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.min.js';
```

In config\routes.yaml:

```
add_post_comment:
    path:   /comment/add/post
    controller: App\Controller\CreatorDashboard\CommentController::addPostComment
    requirements:
     _method:  POST
```

In my javascript .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".post-comment").keyup(function(e) {

        var code = e.which;
        if(code==13)
        {
            var commentText = $(this).val();
            var postId = $(this).data("postid");
            var userId= $(this).data("userid");

            console.log("userId is " + userId + " and postId is " + postId + " and commentText is " + commentText);
            var theRoute = Routing.generate('add_post_comment'); // have also tried Routing.generate('/comment/add/post'); 
            alert("the route is " + theRoute);
```

In the JavaScript console I get the error:

```
Error: The route "add_post_comment" does not exist.
```

Maybe it doesn't see the yaml file?  Is there a step I'm missing?

I have also restarted nginx.

Answer (score 1):

You are not exposing your route like this:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
my_route_to_expose:
    pattern: /foo/{id}/bar
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:index }
    options:
        expose: true
```